# Cannot start httpd service with SSL

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, centos6, certificate-authority

Have an issue where I have installed new certificates on Centos 5 and modified the conf file for the following lines:

> SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls.certs/name.crt
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/name.key
>
> SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/group.ca-bundle

But everytime i start the httpd service i get the following:

```
>     sudo service httpd start
>     Starting httpd: Apache/2.2.15 mod_ssl/2.2.15 (Pass Phrase Dialog)
>     Some of your private key files are encrpyted for security reasons.
>     In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
>     Server servername.co.uk: 443 (RSA)
>     Enter pass phrase:
>     OK: Pass Phrase Dialog successful.                     [FAILED]
```

(Only have basic knowledge with CentOS, so please excuse me for my stupidity in advance!)

So question is what is failing? And where can i find the relevant logs to tell me this?

Comment: Is there any extended information about this in the Apache logfiles?

Comment: Have take a look at almost every logs in /var/log folder but don't even see any logs created for them. This server has been handed down with zero documentation unfortunately!

Comment: Enable debug logging and check if any of the debug logs contain any interesting data.

Comment: Have enabled the debug option but cannot see any logs being recorded. At a complete loss here!

Comment: What if you run the httpd binary manually? With `httpd -e debug`

Comment: @pkhamre thank you, exactly what i was looking for. Gave me a module location error and a phsyical file was missing. If you add this to the answers below, happy to tick it correct.

Comment: Np, answer submitted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `httpd` binary manually with the debug-loglevel to see if you can get any more information from it.

`httpd -e debug`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use certificate pass phrase from certificate
2. Add pass phrase to your apache configuration - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog

Comment: OP quoted: "OK: Pass Phrase Dialog successful.". So I would assume that this problem has nothing to do with the pass phrase.

Comment: I am using the pass phrase, that is entered correctly as you can see from the above output. Placing pass phrase in apache config file is a massive security risk for the certs.